Install Ubuntu on secondary hard drive
Background:
I use Windows 11 on an unsupported device and want to make the dual boot (Windows and Linux) for coding and playing. So I want to install Ubuntu ON MY SECOND DRIVE.
My hardware:
AMD Ryzen 5 2600 six-core
8 GB RAM ddr4
NVIDIA GTS 450
SSD (windows drive)
HDD (files drive I want to put Ubuntu on)
SSD and HDD have MBR and not GPT

I am running on CSM Mode/Bios/Legacy Mode with TPM 2.0 /no secure boot.
I don't prefer partitioning and doing sh## because it's hard for me (I am an easy guy).
THE HDD IS NOT EXTERNAL ITS CONNECTED IN THE PC
The question:
What is the simplest method to install Ubuntu on my second hard disk (HDD)?

I don't see a question, but don't create your install media UEFI only (depends upon tool/options), and boot the install media in legacy/CSM mode (machine settings). Select second disk ,and erase/install with defaults.

This question is similar to: Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details.

@ubfan1 Please rewrite that as an answer

This is a pretty standard legacy install.
Don't create your install media as UEFI only (depends upon tool/options, the ISO can boot both legacy and UEFI), and boot the install media in legacy/CSM mode (machine settings, varies by machine).
Boot the install media (machine settings to boot USB first), select the second disk ,and erase/install with defaults.
The link in comments, Installing Ubuntu On Second Hard Drive has the details for an install.  Note that you can put the grub bootloader on either drive, but assuming grub boots both Windows and Ubuntu, it should go on the drive first in bootorder.
